# Jquerymobile - Listview -Ajax loading -CSS style

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to load data using ajax, listview works charm on intialpage load, during ajax loading css is not loading.

nearly tried everything, like listview refresh,trigger etc..but nothing works out for me.

please help me

my code:

```
$('.more').live("click",function() {
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var CASE = $(".case").attr("id");
var EXTRADATA = $(".extra_data").attr("id");
if(ID) {
    $("#more"+ID).find("#loader").css('display', 'block');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax.php",
            data: "lastpos=" + ID +"&case=" + CASE + "&extradata=" + EXTRADATA,
            cache: false,
    success: function(html){ 
                                $("#video_listing").append(html);
                                $("#more"+ID).remove(); // removing old more button                        

                                }

});
```

I had tried with

$('#video_listing').listview('refresh');

$(html).trigger('create');
          .trigger( "enhance" );

Nothing works out...though lot of topics,covers this question,nothing worksout for me..please help

Comment: Can you include the HTML that the AJAX will be writing to?

Comment: <div id="more<?php echo $video_id; ?>" class="morebox">
   <div align="center">
   <div id="loader"><img src="<?php echo _URL_MOBI; ?>/images/moreajax.gif" /></div>
   <button class="more" id="<?php echo $video_id; ?>">Load More videos</button>
   </div>
   <div class="case" id="browse"></div>
   <div class="extra_data" id="<?php echo $c; ?>"></div>
  </div>

Comment: Where is `#video_listing`? If that ID does not exist, your appending data to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9SVPN/

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.more').live("click", function() {
        $("#myList").append("<li>Added Item</li>");
        $("#myList").listview("refresh");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>Test Page</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="myList">
                <li>Item 1</li>
            </ul>
            <a id="actionBtn" data-role="button" class="more">Add LI</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your question does not define what HTML is returned or what your HTML looks like before the AJAX event, so I am making somassumptions that your returned data is wrapped within `<li></li>`. Then you want to perform the `.listview("refresh")` on the `<ul data-role="listview">` or `<ol data-role="listview">` itself.

Comment: I can't make an AJAX call against your PHP Page to get it's response, so I have to show you an example based on pseudo data. It's not clear what your PHP page sends back after data is posted to it. Also you have not included the details about what the page structure looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Already tried listview,but didnot help.full code..copied here..please check http://jsfiddle.net/sarvnaa/KpWEu/

Comment: I can't make heads or tails from what you posted. It's still not clear what is returned by the SQL Query. I updated my jsFiddle to match more of what you're using. The `.listview("refresh")` works properly. Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9SVPN/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply..let me try again